# Learn math notation for this site

Tags: discussion, mathjax

What is the name of the language used to display math on this site, and how do I learn it?

Is there a post with the basics? I find myself going to the page source to see how others have typed it. Or are there any shortcuts or tricks?

Comment: The **software** is MathJax, but the **language** is $\TeX$.

Comment: I found this useful when I started. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:About

Comment: This is the most helpful possible resource on this, IMHO: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php. You'll start out using it all the time, but as you start to see more and more what LaTeX looks like, you'll start being able to just read and write it like the guy on the matrix looking at the green text.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thing used to display math on this site is called mathjax

Here's a post which can be of help: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you. I am glad you answered before the site police put this on hold. It is a basic question about the use of this site, and should be here, not on the meta site, because many people don't know about the meta site, and it is more convenient here.

Comment: @JLee, no, it would be better on meta. The main site is for math questions, the meta is for questions and issues regarding the main site. The correct statement is "the meta site should be publicized much more vigorously", which is clearly true. In any event, you have learned a valuable lesson; namely, always search the site for answers before posting a question, and always do the same on meta if it seems likely the question will have been asked on meta.

Comment: I agree with @JLee, it should be blindingly obvious where the MathJax reference, tutorials, etc. are to be found. I am no stranger to the site, but it takes a while to find it.

Comment: I (we?) need to be able to search the site itself for the basics, and not have to go elsewhere. Maybe the basics, like TeX could be under another link at the top, Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Basics. Yeah?

Comment: @copper.hat seconded, we need MathJax tutorial link prominent on the main help page.

Comment: I will just point out that help center contains the link to some relevant posts on meta: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation (Whether this information should be have more visibility and whether those links should be placed to some other places in addition to this is for discussion.)